# How to access Sharepoint List Items using an ID

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I am currently working on a nice table that displays the items in a list of "Tasks" on a dispForm page. Each Task is created and initially given a ProjectID depending on which project the task is for. The ProjectID is the actual ID given to the "project" when it is added to the list, therefore it is not actually a parameter in the list of projects while it is a parameter in the list of tasks.

I would like to know how to use the ProjectID parameter in the task list to link to the Project list and grab the ProjectName parameter so that I can display the Project Name in the table. Currently I can not get it to work.

All help is appreciated,
Gale

Comment: Which version of sharepoint is this?

Comment: It is Sharepoint Server 2007 and I'm using Sharepoint Designer 2007 to edit the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this will help: http://blah.winsmarts.com/2007-10-Performing_joins_between_SharePoint_lists.aspx

Comment: It wasn't exactly what I was looking for but it definitely pushed me in the right direction and let me get the table finished. Thanks!